# easystroke error on Archlinux / Manjaro-Linux: libboost_serialization.so.1.64.0

Tags: archlinux, manjaro, easystroke

Got an error while starting easystroke:

> easystroke: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libboost_serialization.so.1.64.0: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error cause of a newer Version of `libboost_serialization.so` (version 1.65.1 instead 1.64.0)

I've created a symbolic link to this new lib, an easystroke works again:

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libboost_serialization.so libboost_serialization.so.1.64.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There already is a bug report for this error: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/55697

It's probably better to install easystroke-git from AUR until this is fixed instead of creating a symlink which has to be manually removed afterwards.